# Angular 8 + IE 11 angular application not working on IE 11

Tags: arrays, angular, internet-explorer, build, production

i am working on angular 8. my application is ready for production but it is not working on IE11. All other browsers  it works fine. on IE 11 it shoes an empty page with some error. i have gone through some websites did the following. still not working :(. thanks in advance for your help

Step 1 :

```
...
"target": "es5"
```

step 2:
not IE 9-10
IE 11

step 3
changes polyfil.ts

"still nothing works"

Comment: have you added the polyfils? see `https://angular.io/guide/browser-support`

Comment: what kind of erros do you get ?

Comment: hey, is it safe to assume that this is an angular CLI app?

Answer (score 0):

What I will suggest is you start debugging with IE. Go to individual files where its throwing the errors. 
Mostly it throws error for the use of

> =>

many others can be. So you need to transpile those codes to more basic code. My goto site for transpiling codes is: [Babel](https://babeljs.io/repl). Just you need to change those codes to transpiled codes.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

You need to follow the following steps to make Angular 8 app run in IE 11:

1. Create a new tsconfig `tsconfig-es5.app.json` next to `tsconfig.app.json` with the below contents:

   ```
   {
    "extends": "./tsconfig.app.json",
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "es5" 
     }
   }
   ```
2. In `angular.json` add two new configuration section under the `build` and `serve` target to provide a new tsconfig:

   ```
   "build": {
     "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
     "options": {
         ...
     },
     "configurations": {
       "production": {
           ...
       },
       "es5": {
         "tsConfig": "./tsconfig-es5.app.json"
       }
     }
   },
   "serve": {
     "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
     "options": {
         ...
     },
     "configurations": {
       "production": {
        ...
       },
       "es5": {
         "browserTarget": "yourAppName:build:es5"
       }
     }
   },
   ```
3. Run the serve with this configuration using the below command:

   ```
   ng serve --configuration es5
   ```

Answer (score 0):

- Un-comment some imports in the polyfill.ts file.
- Install a couple of npm packages.
- Modify the browserslist file (*browserslistrc file with Angular 11 Project*).

**Un-comment a couple of lines under \src\polyfills.ts**

```
// import 'classlist.js';  // Run `npm install --save classlist.js`.

// import 'web-animations-js';  // Run `npm install --save web-animations-js`.
```

**Install a couple of npm packages.**

```
npm install --save classlist.js
npm install --save web-animations-js
```

**Modify the browserslist file.**

Search for the below line.

```
not IE 9-11 # For IE 9-11 support, remove 'not'.
```

Remove not keyword.

```
IE 9-11 # For IE 9-11 support, remove 'not'.
```

***With Angular 11 browserslistrc file***

```
not IE 11 # Angular supports IE 11 only as an opt-in. To opt-in, remove the 'not' prefix on this line.
```

Remove not keyword.

```
IE 11 # Angular supports IE 11 only as an opt-in. To opt-in, remove the 'not' prefix on this line.
```